# generalized Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

How to prove $A'B(B'B)^{-1}B'A \leq A'A$, where $A$,$B$ are $n\times k$ matrices and $B'B$ is assumed to be positive definite? I don't see why it is a Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: If $B^TB$ is invertible, the inequality is equivalent (via Schur complement) to $[A\ B]^T[A\ B]$ being positive semidefinite (which is trivial). Here $A$, $B$ can be any (not necessarily square) matrices with the same number of rows. Can't see CS in it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equivalent to show that 
$$A'(I - B(B'B)^{-1}B')A \geq 0$$
Notice that $H = I - B(B'B)^{-1}B'$ is idempotent and symmetric, hence for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, 
$$x'A'(I - B(B'B)^{-1}B')Ax = (HAx)'(HAx) \geq 0.$$
Hence the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is square (as you've indicated), then the result is obvious:

If $B'B$ is invertible, then so is $B$.  So, we note that
$$
B(B'B)^{-1}B' =
BB^{-1}(B')^{-1}B' = I
$$
So, this whole inequality is just
$$
A'A \leq A'A
$$
which is true, but trivial.  It seems that there's something missing from your question.

Comment: Thank you @Omnomnomnom. I made a mistake. A, B are not square. I corrected the question. How to prove then?